# Algorithm to scale and offset a dataset to fit another dataset

Tags: curve-fitting

I have two sets of datas that are correlated but don't have the same scale nor the same offset. I want to get a polynomial that transform the first dataset into the other one.

I would like to get $\ k_0, k_1, ... ,k_n$ in:
$$
Y_1(t) \approx k_n.(Y_2(t))^n+\ ... \ +k_2.(Y_2(t))^2+k_1.Y_2(t)+k_0
$$

where $Y_1(t)$ and $Y_2(t)$ are my two sets of data

Do such methods/algorithms that would help me to find that polynomial exist ?
Eventually a polynomial of the first degree would do fine $Y_1(t) \approx a.Y_2(t) + b$

Comment: Linear regression of Y1 on a polynomial in Y2

Comment: I don't fully understood what you said (on the polynomial thing) 
But I found what I need ont this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aztcS-3MwH0), Thx